# Making an alert() with PHP and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that submits some data to my PHP file. In my PHP file I have some checks that it does with that data, I then try to make an alert to come up to say something. I can't get any alerts to come up though. All that happens is in the console->network->submit.php->response shows the javascript that should make the alert.

This is my Ajax, which I know works:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if(selectedImageArray.length <= 10){
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    //alert( "Data Saved: " + selectedImageArray );
  });   }else{
        alert( "You can only trade up to 10 items at once." );
    }
});
```

Then in submit.php I do some checks, and have this:

```
        if($QueueCount == 1){
            Echo '<script language="javascript">';
            Echo 'alert( "You already have an active trade, check your Steam profile.");';
            echo '</script>';
        }else{
            Echo '<script language="javascript">';
            Echo 'alert("You are currently in the trade Queue, you should receive a trade request soon.");';
            echo '</script>';
        }
```

This should make an alert, but it just outputs `<script language="javascript">alert( "You already have an active trade, check your Steam profile.");</script>` into the network tab, like I said.

How can I make this work to make an alert pop-up from the PHP file?

Comment: You should just return the text strings and handle the alert in your success function like the commented-out line you have now. `msg` contains your javascript block but if you don't do anything with it, nothing will happen.

Comment: ajax calls return text. that's all. you're just getting some text (that happens to be javascript), and it'll stay text until you put that text somewhere so that it becomes executable - e.g inserting that text into your document somewhere as an actual DOM `<script>` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to output javascript from the php, without outputting it in your ajax callback, won't work.

The easiest way to do what you want, is to return the string with your php, and handle the outputting to your javascript.

something like :

```
if($QueueCount == 1){
        Echo "You already have an active trade, check your Steam profile.";
    }else{
        Echo "You are currently in the trade Queue, you should receive a trade request soon.";
    }
```

and for the javascript

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  if(selectedImageArray.length <= 10){
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray}
      }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
      });   
  }else{
        alert( "You can only trade up to 10 items at once." );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You javascript code must look like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {  
  if(selectedImageArray.length <= 10){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      data: {selectedImageArray: selectedImageArray},
      success: function(data,status){
        eval(data)
      }
    });   
  }else{
    alert( "You can only trade up to 10 items at once." );
  }
});
```

And your php code should not declare script tags:

```
    if($QueueCount == 1){
        echo 'alert( "You already have an active trade, check your Steam profile.");';
    }else{
        echo 'alert("You are currently in the trade Queue, you should receive a trade request soon.");';
    }
```

Make sure that this is the only output from your php file.

Also this code also needs several improvements before go to production, such as callback to error on server-side processing, check if ajax didn't fail at all due to network issues and XSS protection, to list a few.

Comment: The more I make my site the more problems arise. Can you show me any specific ways for fixing these other problems, or point me in the direction to learn about them?

Comment: sure: learn about XSS protection here: http://www.google.com.br/about/appsecurity/learning/xss/ and for the possible of fails you can use a function as  'error' param on your $.ajax call. for server-side processing issue (I.E if the data received in the script wasn't what you expected) you can echo a string like 'error data malformed' and use HTTP header 400 as well and then check for its header or returned text on you success function to deal with it accordingly.